# Why is my Samsung 850 Pro booting up slowly?

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd, performance

I am running Windows 10 Pro and I have a Gigabyte GA-Z170X-Gaming 3 motherboard with 16 GB of RAM. I also have a mechanical hard drive for mass storage. But the problem is it takes about 15-20 seconds for my computer to boot up from the press of the power button to the login screen, but the 850 pro should be booting faster than that. It's a 512 GB Samsung 850 Pro and I've used about 200 GB. My friend has a 128 GB Samsung 850 Evo and he's booting up in 6 seconds. Am I missing something here? I have Samsung Magician installed with Max Performance Optimization, Fast Boot enabled, and Fast startup and hibernate on.

Comment: install the WPT (which is part of the Windows 10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe select CPU, Disk, fileIO, network and under perf scenario **Boot**. Run 1 boot trace, after you're back in windows, compress the ETL in a 7z/RAR (to reduce the file size), upload the compressed file to onedrive, dropbox, create a share link and pots the link here.

Comment: have you captured a trace?

Answer (score 0):

AHCI mode in Gigabyte motherboard's firmware settings can be slow booting up. On the other hand when it is in IDE mode it sometimes will not recognize the SSD. For more information, search for Gigabyte GA-Z170X motherboard in the [Official Gigabyte Forum](https://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/).

Comment: But according to Samsung Magician, AHCI mode is enabled.

Comment: AHCI is the default setting for SSDs so Samsung Magician enabled it, as it should have.

Comment: So I should switch to IDE mode?

Comment: IDE mode doesn't boot at all on my computer that has a Gigabyte motherboard + Intel processor + SSD. I found out how to change the firmware settings to make it boot from the Official Gigabyte Forum. The Official Gigabyte Forum is not searchable, so to find anything useful you have to browse through all of the pages, in the motherboard -> Intel or AMD section of the Official Gigabyte Forum.

Comment: Oh boy... I'm starting to regret picking Gigabyte...

Comment: Gigabyte makes rugged, reliable, technologically innovative motherboards that are good for gaming. Search through the Official Gigabyte Forum. It's worth reading whatever information it has about your motherboard.